# Awk While and For Loop

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files (file1 and file2)

```
file1:

-11.61
-11.27
-10.47

file2:

NAME
NAME
NAME
```

I want to use awk to search for first occurrence of NAME in file 2 and add the 1st line of file1 before it, and so on. The desired output is

```
########## Energy:              -11.61
NAME
########## Energy:              -11.27
NAME
########## Energy:              -10.47
NAME
```

I tried this code

```
#!/bin/bash

file=file1
while IFS= read line
do
        # echo line is stored in $line
        echo $line
awk '/MOLECULE/{print "### Energy: "'$line'}1' file2` > output
done < "$file"
```

But this was the output that I got

```
########## Energy:              -10.47
NAME
########## Energy:              -10.47
NAME
########## Energy:              -10.47
NAME
```

I don't know why the script is putting only the last value of file1 before each occurrence of NAME in file2.

I appreciate your help!

**Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question. Here are the samples of my files (energy.txt and sample.mol2):**

[user]$cat energy.txt

```
-11.61
-11.27
-10.47
```

[user]$cat sample.mol2

```
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
methane
5 4 1 0 0 
SMALL
NO_CHARGES


@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  1 C        2.8930    -0.4135    -1.3529 C.3   1 <1>   0.0000 
  2 H1       3.9830    -0.4135    -1.3529 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  3 H2       2.5297     0.3131    -0.6262 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  4 H3       2.5297    -1.4062    -1.0869 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  5 H4       2.5297    -0.1476    -2.3456 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
@<TRIPOS>BOND
  1   1   2  1   
  2   1   3  1   
  3   1   4  1   
  4   1   5  1   

@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
ammonia
4 3 1 0 0 
SMALL
NO_CHARGES


@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  1 N        8.6225    -3.5397    -1.3529 N.3   1 <1>   0.0000 
  2 H1       9.6325    -3.5397    -1.3529 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  3 H2       8.2858    -2.8663    -0.6796 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  4 H3       8.2858    -4.4595    -1.1065 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
@<TRIPOS>BOND
  1   1   2  1   
  2   1   3  1   
  3   1   4  1   

@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
water
3 2 1 0 0 
SMALL
NO_CHARGES


@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  1 O        7.1376     3.8455    -3.4206 O.3   1 <1>   0.0000 
  2 H1       8.0976     3.8455    -3.4206 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  3 H2       6.8473     4.4926    -2.7736 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
@<TRIPOS>BOND
  1   1   2  1   
  2   1   3  1
```

**This is the output that I need**

```
########## Energy:              -11.61
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
methane
5 4 1 0 0 
SMALL
NO_CHARGES


@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  1 C        2.8930    -0.4135    -1.3529 C.3   1 <1>   0.0000 
  2 H1       3.9830    -0.4135    -1.3529 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  3 H2       2.5297     0.3131    -0.6262 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  4 H3       2.5297    -1.4062    -1.0869 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  5 H4       2.5297    -0.1476    -2.3456 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
@<TRIPOS>BOND
  1   1   2  1   
  2   1   3  1   
  3   1   4  1   
  4   1   5  1   
########## Energy:              -11.27
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
ammonia
4 3 1 0 0 
SMALL
NO_CHARGES


@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  1 N        8.6225    -3.5397    -1.3529 N.3   1 <1>   0.0000 
  2 H1       9.6325    -3.5397    -1.3529 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  3 H2       8.2858    -2.8663    -0.6796 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  4 H3       8.2858    -4.4595    -1.1065 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
@<TRIPOS>BOND
  1   1   2  1   
  2   1   3  1   
  3   1   4  1   
########## Energy:              -10.47
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
water
3 2 1 0 0 
SMALL
NO_CHARGES


@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  1 O        7.1376     3.8455    -3.4206 O.3   1 <1>   0.0000 
  2 H1       8.0976     3.8455    -3.4206 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
  3 H2       6.8473     4.4926    -2.7736 H     1 <1>   0.0000 
@<TRIPOS>BOND
  1   1   2  1   
  2   1   3  1
```

Comment: Your question would be MUCH clearer if you posted some actual values for "NAME" in your input and output instead of just repeating the word "NAME" multiple times.

Comment: Now, what do you want the output to be?

Comment: I just updated the required output. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} /@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE/
    {print "########## Energy:             ", a[++i]}1' energy.txt sample.mol2
```

**Explanation:**

- FNR - line number of the current file
- NR  - line number of the total lines of two files.
- `NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}` is applied for the first `energy.txt`
- so above statement populates an array with index as `1,2,3...` and value as `$0`
- `/@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE/` search is executed on the 2nd file `sample.mol2`
- When above search is successful it prints quoted static string and a line from array created from 1st file
- `++i` moves the counter to next element in array after printing

Comment: If I have text between the pattern NAME and add }1' at the end of the line to print everything, only the first value of file1 is printed in file2 and NAME is printed twice every time.
Sorry about my lack of knowledge I would appreciate some help with this.
Thanks!

Comment: I can try to help but need to understand your input files better. Can you edit your question and provide this new inout data format in question so that I can understand better and fix the code.

Comment: thanks anubhava. I just updated my question with improved sample files.

Comment: There was an improvement. The @<TRIPOS>MOLECULE now is not being printed twice, but still only the first value of energy.txt is being printed in before @<TRIPOS>MOLECULE in sample.mol2

Comment: Awesome. Thanks anubhava, this works perfectly.Could you give a little explanation as to what different parts of the script are doing?

Comment: Yes sure adding explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
paste -d "\n" <(sed 's/^/########## Energy:              /' file1) file2
```

```
########## Energy:              -11.61
NAME
########## Energy:              -11.27
NAME
########## Energy:              -10.47
NAME
```

Or, sticking with awk

```
awk '{
    print "########## Energy:              " $0
    getline < "file2"
    print
}' file1
```

Comment: If process substitution is not available, `sed '...' file1 | paste -d "\n" - file2` should also work.

Comment: The awk code worked. On the other hand when I tried to use it in a file that has some text between the pattern NAME only the first value is returned correctly.

Comment: Well, you should have added that to your question.

Comment: Sorry Glenn, i tried to give a simple example. But I just updated my question with a sample of my real problem. Thanks